# Не ясна работа рекурсивной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Здравствуйте.
В учебнике приводится мысленный эксперимент:

> Что вернёт этот код?

```
def fib(x):
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)

print(fib(4))
```

Код возвращает:

> 5

Но ведь на 4 итерации 'х' принимает значение 1! Почему не срабатывает return и не возвращается единица, завершая работу функции?

Comment: А что, для питона нет отладчиков? Тоггда выводите значения `x` в процессе работы и сами всё увидите.

Comment: Есть отладчик. На 4 итерации он показывает что аргумент, передающийся в функцию, равен 1.

Comment: Значит, в этом случае происходит выход из функции. Но не завершение рекурсии.

Comment: Но почему функция не завершается на 'return 1' ?

Comment: попробуйте [по шагам выполнить и посмотрите на возвращаемые значения на каждом шагу](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20fib%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%200%20or%20x%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fib%28x%20-%201%29%20%2B%20fib%28x%20-%202%29%0A%0Aprint%28fib%284%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: jfs громадное спасибо за ресурс. Всё стало понятно за одну минуту.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что в первой итерации не выполняется if. Когда начинает выполняться блок else **первый в коде return работает уже не на print, который ждёт значение вне функции, а на вызов из блока else.**

Таким образом строка return 1 никогда не сможет вернуть значение в print.

Пошаговое выполнение можно посмотреть [здесь](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20fib%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%200%20or%20x%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fib%28x%20-%201%29%20%2B%20fib%28x%20-%202%29%0A%0Aprint%28fib%284%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) . 
Большое спасибо [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) за ссылку на полезный для всех новичков ресурс.

Answer (score 0):

Такая рекурсия называется каскадной рекурсией. Попробуйте расписать с помощью так называемых формуляров. Прикладываю пример того, как раскладывал на формуляры один из примеров
[image: вот именно это и есть этот пример (сама функция написана на haskell)]

кстати, мне стало гораздо легче понимать рекурсию после того, как разобрался с ней в haskell. Поэтому рекомендую